# How to implement a custom user List in Viewmodel (Java - Android)

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to develop an Android app using MVVM and the latest Jetpack components (relevant to this case: Room, Navigation and LiveData)

I have a User database created with Room, and in one of my Fragments I have to display a list of these Users, but not all of them, just the ones that have certain ID. Depending on where I start this fragment within the app, this list changes (different Users get displayed)

Every time I return to this fragment, it gets recreated (for what I understand, that's how Navigation works), but I have a problem figuring how to avoid this "custom" User list from reloading data from the database each time I create the view, since otherwise the RecyclerView that holds this list "flashes" for a split second while the app is accesing the DB.

This is what I've tried to do in my Viewmodel (it's clearly wrong but maybe it can help you understand what I'm trying to do)

```java
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private LiveData<List<User>> customUserList;
private UserRepository mUserRepository;

public LiveData<List<User>> getUsersForGroup(int groupId) {
        if(customUserList != null){
            return customUserList;
        } else {
            customUserList = mUserRepository.getUsersForGroup(groupId);
            return customUserList;
        }
    }
```

I can think some "hacky" ways of doing this, but there has to be a correct way of doing it.

Should I use in this case a ViewModelFactory? And if that's the case, how can I implement this? I couldn't find much information about this, and what I found is written in Kotlin.

What's the right approach?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the particular concern with querying the database? Are you experiencing specific performance problems? I mean, you could add caching to your `UserRepository`, but that may be a premature optimization.

Comment: You are trying to say you want to create a `model class` for `User` which will have `id, firstName, secondName` and things like this am I correct ?

Comment: @CommonsWare My problem is that every time this Fragment loads (which happens all the time while using the app), the recycler view for the User list "flashes" for half a second while the app access the Database. I want to find a way of avoiding this. (for example, if I ask the full list of users from my Viewmodel, this "reload" doesn't happen because this list is stored in the Viewmodel).

Comment: @Spritzig No, I've already created the model class and it's working

Comment: "the recycler view for the User list "flashes" for half a second while the app access the Database" -- I'm uncertain what "flashes" means in this context. If you mean that the `RecyclerView` is empty, then gets populated, and you are trying to avoid this... focus first on making sure your Room is set up properly. For example, do you have indexes set up to handle the query that sits behind `getUsersForGroup()`?

Comment: If after database tuning you still feel that you have unacceptable performance, either cache in an activity-level `ViewModel` or in your `UserRepository`. In theory, caching in the repository would be the right answer, but that tends to break Room's "here's a fresh query result, as the data may have changed" feature.

Comment: @CommonsWare Now that you mention, I get this warning when I compile the app: "group_id colum references a foreign key but it is not part of an index", maybe that's the problem. I will try to find out how to fix this and see if that fixes my problem. If you have any information or resources to help me with this I would appreciate it, since I don't have much experience.

Comment: You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you post your entities and DAO, and perhaps we can help you identify the indexes to add.